# How do I collect a bounty in Elite: Dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

What do you press to collect a bounty? I am in a Federation port after killing a pirate, but I haven't received a bounty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which game is this about?  You'll want to make sure that it's tagged appropriately.

Comment: Elite, apparantly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elite_%28video_game%29 according to google

Comment: Elite: Dangerous is the only one in the series with the modern sense of "achievements", so that seems more likely given the user's tag.

Comment: @JeremyAvalon Yes, that's what I was thinking, too.

Answer (score 9):

When you destroy a wanted vessel, you receive a bounty voucher valid in one or more jurisdictions (it could be general like "Federation", or a specific minor faction like "Achenar Empire League"). To collect on this bounty voucher, dock at any station in the system you earned the bounty in, and go to the "Contacts" menu in Station Services. From there, go to the Local Security Office to turn in your bounty claims, and receive credits.

Comment: You can also dock anywhere that specific faction is present, which, if it says only "Empire" or "Federation", will be a lot more than just the one.

Comment: I do not know how to go to the local security office but I will try now.